# Finding residue of complex function using Laurent series

Tags: complex-analysis, residue-calculus, laurent-series

I want to find the residue of $f(z)=z^me^{1/z}$ at $0$. Could you please check if this is correct?

$z^me^{1/z }=z^m\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{(\frac{1}{z})^k}{k!}=z^m\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{k!}z^{-k}=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{k!}z^{m-k}$

And at $k=m+1$ we get $z^{-1}$ so the residue of the function is $\frac{1}{(m+1)!}$ since it's the coefficient of $(z-0)^k$?

Comment: That is correct. What are your doubts about it?

Comment: Thanks. I just wanted to check.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/434606/calculate-residue-at-essential-singularity